# Why does Python have `reversed`?

Tags: python, language-design

Why does Python have the built-in function [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)?

Why not just use `x[::-1]` instead of `reversed(x)`?

---

**Edit**: *@TanveerAlam [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26985860/2223706) that* `reversed` *is not actually a function, but rather a class, despite being listed on the page [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html)*.

Comment: Ask Guido? Hes the one who will know.

Comment: `for x in my_list[::-1]` is just ugly.

Comment: `x[::-1]` is much less efficient than `reversed(x)`; it creates a whole new list, whereas `reversed()` simply creates an iterator that walks in the opposite direction.

Comment: idk why people downvote good question, this type of question is really good

Comment: @Hackaholic, I disagree. "Why does X have Y?" inherently requires either research into publicly-available email archives (with respect to creators' intent) or firsthand knowledge (ie. the person who made the decision to be present on StackOverflow) to have an objective and factual answer; otherwise it's speculation and opinion, which are off-topic here. Now, "what benefit does Y have that X does not?" is a fine question, but it's a **different** question, and if that's what was intended, then it's what should have been asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reversed` returns a reverse iterator.

`[::-1]` asks the object for a slice

Python objects try to return what you probably expect

```
>>> [1, 2, 3][::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
>>> "123"[::-1]
'321'
```

This is convenient - particularly for strings and tuples.

But remember the majority of code doesn't need to reverse strings.

The most important role of `reversed()` is **making code easier to read and understand**.

The fact that it returns an iterator without creating a new sequence is of secondary importance

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-322-reverse-iteration)

> PEP 322: Reverse Iteration A new built-in function, reversed(seq)(),
>   takes a sequence and returns an iterator that loops over the elements
>   of the sequence in reverse order.

```
>>>
>>> for i in reversed(xrange(1,4)):
...    print i
...
3
2
1
```

> Compared to extended slicing, such as range(1,4)[::-1], reversed() is
>   easier to read, runs faster, and uses substantially less memory.
>
> Note that reversed() only accepts sequences, not arbitrary iterators.
>   If you want to reverse an iterator, first convert it to a list with
>   list().

```
>>>
>>> input = open('/etc/passwd', 'r')
>>> for line in reversed(list(input)):
...   print line
...
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> a[::-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> reversed(a)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x10dbf5390>
```

The first notation is generating the reverse eagerly; the second is giving you a reverse iterator, which is possibly cheaper to acquire, as it has potential to only generate elements as needed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `reversed` is not a built-in function.

```
>>> type(reversed)
<type 'type'>
```

It's a class which itrates over a sequence and gives a reverse order of sequence.

Try:

```
>>> help(reversed)
Help on class reversed in module __builtin__:

class reversed(object)
 |  reversed(sequence) -> reverse iterator over values of the sequence
```

And when we pass a parameter to it, it acts as a iterator,

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> obj = reversed(l)
>>> obj
<listreverseiterator object at 0x0220F950>
>>> obj.next()
4
>>> obj.next()
3
>>> obj.next()
2
>>> obj.next()
1
>>> obj.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

whereas a slice operation returns the whole list which is not memory efficient for larger lists.

That is why, in Python 2, we have `range` (which returns whole list) as well as `xrange` (which generates each element on every iteration).

```
>>> l[::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I guess this page called [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html) is slightly misleading since I now see there's both classes (`reversed`, `zip`, etc) and functions.

Answer (score 1):

reversed return a reverse iterator.

x[::-1] return a list.

```
In [1]: aaa = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [4]: aaa[::-1]
Out[4]: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

In [5]: timeit(aaa[::-1])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 206 ns per loop

In [6]: reversed(aaa)
Out[6]: <listreverseiterator at 0x104310d50>

In [7]: timeit(reversed(aaa))
10000000 loops, best of 3: 182 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz'];
print type(reversed(aList))

bList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc', 'xyz'];
print type(bList[::-1])
```

Output:

```
<type 'listreverseiterator'>
<type 'list'>
```

The `reversed` function returns a reverse iterator. The `[::-1]` returns a list.

Answer (score -1):

Because reversed returns an iterator.

Comment: So does `(elem for elem in listOfThings[::-1])`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, yes, but that one constructs an inverted list and iterates over it, completely defeating the point (with respect to memory and performance efficiency).

Comment: I'm not saying using the slice is better, but "returning an iterator" isn't the whole reason for it as other answers have shown.